# Delete items from rails database if boolean true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up an admin backend in Rails. There are a list of orders. By default when submitted by the end user shows as "processing" on the admin side. If the admin sends out the order he can press the "processing" button and set it to completed.

I'm trying to have a "Delete All Completed Orders" button above the table.

Here is the admin controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :ensure_admin_user

  def index
    @orders = Order.last(5)
    @posts = Post.last(5)
    @items = Item.last(5)
  end

  def posts
    @posts = Post.all.page(params[:page])
  end

  def items
  end

  private

  def ensure_admin_user
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

And the index file:

```
<h1>Admin page</h1>
<h3>Orders</h3>
<div class="form-group"><%= link_to 'View all orders', orders_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %><%= link_to 'Delete All Completed Orders', @completed, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %></div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr class="order-<%= order.id %><%= ' bg-success' if order.completed %>">
      <td><%= link_to order.id, order %></td>
      <td><%= order.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= order.user.email %></td>
      <td><%= order.total_price %></td>
      <td><%= truncate(order.address, length: 100, separator: ' ') %></td>
      <td><%= truncate(order.comment, length: 100, separator: ' ') %></td>
      <% if order.completed %>
        <td><%= button_to 'Completed', completed_order_path(order.id), method: :put, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-success' %></td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= button_to 'Processing', completed_order_path(order.id), method: :put, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-default' %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Haven't worked with rails in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new controller action in your admin controller like so.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :ensure_admin_user

  def index
    @orders = Order.last(5)
    @posts = Post.last(5)
    @items = Item.last(5)
  end
  ....
  def destroy_completed_items
    Item.destroy_all(completed: true)
    redirect_to items_url
  end
end
```

Don't forget to add the route to your config/routes.rb

```
resources :admin do
  delete 'destroy_completed_items', on: :collection
end
```

Then simply call the action from a button/link in your view.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete All Completed Orders', destroy_completed_items_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Comment: What about the actual button it self? How do I call the route? <%= link_to 'Delete All Completed Orders', destroy_completed_items, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>

Comment: Almost exactly like you have it

    <%= link_to 'Delete All Completed Orders', destroy_completed_items_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>

If that doesn't work - you can run rake routes to see what the exact route is for your new action. You also need to redirect after you delete - see edited answer.